# Python regular expression always return None

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I want to get userid from url like:

```
http://space.bilibili.com/1950746/#!/channel/detail?cid=1757&order=&page=1
```

and it should be like 1950746.

And here is the code:

```
url='http://space.bilibili.com/1950746/#!/channel/detail?cid=1757&order=&page=1'
b=userid=re.match(r'\d{7}', url)
print(b)
```

The result is None.

Comment: re.serach and \d+ for your search.

Comment: @Zara please summarise the content of your link, at least by using something else than "link" for the link.

Comment: Got it, thanks@Sebastian Proske

Answer (score 0):

Using `re.match` gives an implicit `^` at the beginning of the string. Use `re.search` to find anywhere in string.